# When we should start reviewing/merging/deleting/discussing tags for the site?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've already noticed a lot of similar and potentially duplicate tags for the site, and I was wondering when during the site's beta is a good time to start asking for community feedback on merging 2 tags (such as [online-interaction](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-interaction) and [social-media](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media)) and also removing of duplicate tags? Can we start discussing these tags now or should we wait a while first as we learn what sort of questions and tags users on the site are likely to ask?

Comment: Online interaction and social media are not the same thing.

Comment: Using social Media is a form of online interaction though.

Comment: So? Blueberries are a kind of fruit but that doesn't mean both tags aren't valuable.

Comment: Precisely, which I'm asking when should we have this conversation (if having the extra [tag:social-media] is worth it? (i.e. if barely any tags are used then there's no point in it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever we like.

Though we should remember a couple of things:

1. The CMs are the people who will actually be carrying out any decisions that we make since we don't have moderators at the moment, so having them actually merged/deleted will depend on their time.
2. As a new site, we may not see the value of some tags initially, so it can be difficult to determine if, in fact, two tags **are** duplicates of each other. We can't expect to be perfect from the outset.

So, considering these two things, nothing prevents us from, right now, addressing these questions on Meta. In fact, if we wish to ask the CMs to make such changes for us, they prefer to see Meta consensus before they take such action.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Catija's answer](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/108/57), but would just like to add. If there's two of same tag - but pluralised, e.g. [friend](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friend) and [friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friends) the less popular tag can be edited out and the more popular one edited in.

A tag with no posts attached to it, will be automatically deleted over 24 hours. I'm not sure the exact time the Stack Exchange wheels turn to make that happen.

**Caveat.** . 
From [the comments](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/when-we-should-start-reviewing-merging-deleting-discussing-tags-for-the-site/111?noredirect=1#comment219_111):

> The system won't let you add a tag that is one letter off of an
>   existing tag until the older tag "dies"... so if the "friend" tag
>   existed and we wanted to use "friends" instead, we'd have to remove
>   "friend" from all of the questions with it (potentially leaving some
>   questions untagged), and wait 24 hours before being able to create the
>   "friends" tag... unless a CM fixes it for us.

[Add some small amount of flexibility in the plural tag creation rule to allow users to fix newly-created tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277403/add-some-small-amount-of-flexibility-in-the-plural-tag-creation-rule-to-allow-us)

Comment: This isn't technically possible, actually. The system won't let you add a tag that is one letter off of an existing tag until the older tag "dies"... so if the "friend" tag existed and we wanted to use "friends" instead, we'd have to remove "friend" from all of the questions with it (potentially leaving some questions untagged), and wait 24 hours before being able to create the "friends" tag... unless a CM fixes it for us. Related MSE post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277403/add-some-small-amount-of-flexibility-in-the-plural-tag-creation-rule-to-allow-us

Comment: @Catija ah ok. I'll edit and add you comment.