# "Greeting" to "Greetings"

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

In [this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/623/how-to-respond-to-whats-up), the tag [greeting](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greeting) is used, this tag should be changed to [greetings](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greetings) to match up with tags such as [conversations](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversations) and [friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friends) (other plural tags). Also related to [this meta post](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/should-tags-be-pluralised-or-singular?noredirect=1&lq=1) related to plural/singular tags.

(also worth noting due to the 1-letter difference I am unable to create/replace the [greeting](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greeting) with [greetings](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greetings))

Comment: Related (possible duplicate, maybe): https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/112/102.

Comment: @HDE226868 I'm requesting a Mod to change it unless the community objects, so sorry if it seems like a duplicate, it's why I tried to use the [tag:feature-request] tag :P

Comment: It should be plural.

Comment: When A&C was in beta, Robert said to just flag this sort of thing. https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/disable-the-s-restriction-temporarily-in-the-closed-beta#comment93_50

Comment: @Catija ah okay thanks, willdo, I just posted here because that's what it said lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is done. I think that was a good change.

<sub>posting just so it is "answered"</sub>